# How to return definition argument

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have this definition

```
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN (DDRD, PORTD, PD6)
```

I want to write two more definitions, in order to get `PORTD` and `PD6` values, something like this

```
#define GET_PORT(_PORT_) /*some magic goes here*/
#define GET_PIN(_PIN_) /*some magic goes here*/

uint8_t port = GET_PORT(LED_CLOCK_PIN);
uint8_t pin = GET_PIN(LED_CLOCK_PIN);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN (DDRD, PORTD, PD6)

#define SND(A, B, C) B
#define GET_PORT(X) SND X

uint8_t port = GET_PORT(LED_CLOCK_PIN);
```

`gcc -E` processes it to `uint8_t port = PORTD;`. <s>I'm not sure if this is fully portable and guaranteed by standard.</s>

Comment: @Pablo Expansion goes: `GET_PORT(LED_CLOCK_PIN)` -> `GET_PORT((DDRD, PORTD, PD6))` -> `SND (DDRD, PORTD, PD6)` -> `PORTD`

Answer (score 1):

If you were permitted to change you first define to:

```
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN  DDRD, PORTD, PD6
```

then with C99 you can do (not tested):

```
#define GET_PORT(x)  (((int[]){x})[1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately those defines are not changeable :(

Comment: And zch's solution is better, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you would want to parameterize the port instead of accessing it directly by name? That is, instead of

```
#define GET_PORT
```

Would it make more sense to have something like

```
#define GET_PORT_D (port.D)
#define LED_CLOCK_PIN 0x10 //Bit 5 of the port.D register, for example
#define GET_LED_CLOCK_PIN ( (port.D & LED_CLOCK_PIN) >> 4)
```

This way, there is no ambiguity to what you're doing with the port, so it improves readability. Second, the likelihood that you are changing what `LED_CLOCK_PIN` actually means (since it accesses hardware) is probably pretty low, so again why not make the code unambiguous.

Comment: Pins, such as `LED_CLOCK_PIN` are already defined and I don't want to modify this. There are plenty of them. So I want to make one definition to get values from all pins/ports.